# Pyqt4: pyqtSignal with keyword arguments?

Tags: python-2.7, qt4, pyqt4

in the following executable code I am about to pass some keyword arguments the `pyqtSignal()`. Without keyword arguments it does work. Well, I know `pyqtSignal()` doesn't support keyword arguments. So I have to admit I don't have any ideas to solve this problem. But I want to avoid the implementation detail.

Some suggestions or alternatives?

```
from sys import argv

from PyQt4.QtCore import Qt, pyqtSignal

from PyQt4.QtGui import QDialog, QApplication, QPushButton, \
     QFormLayout, QTextEdit 

class Form(QDialog):

    test_signal = pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QDialog.__init__(self, parent)

        self.test_signal.connect(self.print_it)

        self.init_ui()

    def init_ui(self):


        self.pushButton_pyqt_signal = QPushButton()
        self.pushButton_pyqt_signal.setText("pyqtSignal") 

        layout = QFormLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.pushButton_pyqt_signal)

        self.setLayout(layout)
        self.setWindowTitle("Log In")

        self.pushButton_pyqt_signal.clicked.connect(lambda: self.test_signal.emit('normal argument', keyword_arg_second='Ok, second'))

    def print_it(self, argument, keyword_arg_first=None, keyword_arg_second=None):
        print "Do some with argument", argument
        print "Do some with first keyword:", keyword_arg_first
        print "Do some with second keyword", keyword_arg_second
        return

app = QApplication(argv)
form = Form()
form.show()
app.exec_()
```

**Update #1**

```
from sys import argv

from PyQt4.QtCore import Qt, pyqtSignal, QObject

from PyQt4.QtGui import QDialog, QApplication, QPushButton, \
     QFormLayout

class WorkClass(QObject):

    test_signal = pyqtSignal(object)

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QObject.__init__(self, parent)

    def run(self):
        self.test_signal.emit(self.test_signal.emit('normal argument', keyword_arg_second="Ok, second"))

class Form(QDialog):

    start_work_class_signal = pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QDialog.__init__(self, parent)

        self.init_ui()

    def init_ui(self):


        self.pushButton_pyqt_signal = QPushButton()
        self.pushButton_pyqt_signal.setText("pyqtSignal") 

        layout = QFormLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.pushButton_pyqt_signal)

        self.setLayout(layout)
        self.setWindowTitle("Testing window")

        self.pushButton_pyqt_signal.clicked.connect(self.start_with_work)

    def print_it(self, argument, keyword_arg_first=None, keyword_arg_second=None):
        print "argument", argument
        print "See first:", keyword_arg_first
        print "See second", keyword_arg_second
        return

    def start_with_work(self):
        work_class = WorkClass()
        work_class.test_signal.connect(self.print_it)

        self.start_work_class_signal.connect(work_class.run)
        self.start_work_class_signal.emit()

app = QApplication(argv)
form = Form()
form.show()
app.exec_()
```

Comment: Seems like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Why don't you just *call* the slot inside the `lambda`? What's the point of emitting a signal?

Comment: I have updated my code. I want to simulate my problem. You were right, in this simple example I cann just call the slot inside lambda, but in my program I have two classe and I want to work with pyqtSignal to obtain the data encapsulation.

Comment: This looks like poor data encapsulation because the signal emitter would have to know the signature of the slots that are connected to it. Signals should be generic broadcasters that send messages without ever knowing (or caring) if anything is listening them. It's up to the receivers to decide how those messages should be handled.

Answer (score -1):

Take a look to the docs, might be helpful: http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/new_style_signals_slots.html

Comment: The linked doc doesn't help. I want to pass keyword argument the pyqtSignal. In your link I see no example.

Comment: Then, could you please elaborate a bit more on what you're trying to do?

Comment: I have added a new code. In this code you see I don't always need three arguments. Somethimes I need the first or/and the third argument. And the other point is: several places in the program this method is used.And I don't want to repeat the same tasks twice and three times. In some situation I only need the 'normal' argument - without the two keyword arguments. And there is a situation, I only need the third keyword argument and so on.

Comment: @Sophus. That's what `lambda` or `functools.partial` are for.